# Finding the Matching Characters after Pattern in R DataFrame

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, loops

I am fairly new to string manipulation, and I am stuck on a problem regarding string and character data in an R dataframe. I am attempting to extract numeric values from a long string **after a pattern** and then store the result as a new column in my dataframe. I have a fairly large dataset, and I am attempting to get out some useful information stored in a column called "notes".

For instance, the strings I am interested in always follow this pattern (there is nothing significant about the tasks):

```
df$notes[1] <- "On 5 June, some people walked down the street in this area. [size=around 5]" 
df$notes[2] <- "On 6 June, some people rode bikes down the street in this area. [size= nearly 4]" 
df$notes[3] <- "On 7 June, some people walked into a grocery store in this area. [size= about 100]"
```

In some columns, we do not get a numeric value, and that is a problem I can deal with after I get a solution to this one. Those rows follow something similar to this:

```
df$notes[4] <- "On 10 July, an hundreds of people drank water from this fountain [size=hundreds]"
df$notes[5] <- "on 15 August, an unreported amount of people drove their cars down the street. [size= no report]"
```

I am trying to extract the entire match after "size= *(some quantifier)*", and store the value into an appended column of my dataframe.

Eventually, I need to write a loop that goes through this column (call it "notes") in my dataframe, and storing the values "5, 4, 100" into a new column (call it "est_size").

Ideally, my new column will look like this:

```
df$est_size[1] <- "around 5"
df$est_size[2] <- "nearly 4"
df$est_size[3] <- "about 100"
df$est_size[4] <- "hundreds"
df$est_size[5] <- "no report"
```

Code that I have tried / stuck on:

```
stringr::str_extract(notes[1], \w[size=]\d"
```

but all I get back is "size=" and not the value *after*

Thank you in advance for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `str_extract`:

```
library(stringr)
trimws(str_extract(df$notes, "(?<=size=)[\\w\\s]+"))
[1] "around 5"  "nearly 4"  "about 100" "hundreds"  "no report"
```

Here, we use positive lookbehind `(?<=...)` to assert an accompanying pattern for what we want to extract: we want to extract the alphanumeric string(s) that follow after `size=`so we put `size=`into the lookbehind expression and extract whatever alphanumeric chars (`\\w`) and whitespace chars (`\\s`) (but not special chars such as `]`!) come after it.

Comment: Hi Chris, Much appreciated, and especially want to thank you for the notes you gave on the regex provided.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a regex lookaround to match one or more characters that are not a closing square bracket `]` after the `size=`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(est_size = trimws(str_extract(notes, '(?<=size=)[^\\]]+')))
```

-output

```
df                                                                                           #notes  est_size
#1                      On 5 June, some people walked down the street in this area. [size=around 5]  around 5
#2                 On 6 June, some people rode bikes down the street in this area. [size= nearly 4]  nearly 4
#3               On 7 June, some people walked into a grocery store in this area. [size= about 100] about 100
#4                 On 10 July, an hundreds of people drank water from this fountain [size=hundreds]  hundreds
#5 on 15 August, an unreported amount of people drove their cars down the street. [size= no report] no report
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(notes = c("On 5 June, some people walked down the street in this area. [size=around 5]", 
"On 6 June, some people rode bikes down the street in this area. [size= nearly 4]", 
"On 7 June, some people walked into a grocery store in this area. [size= about 100]", 
"On 10 July, an hundreds of people drank water from this fountain [size=hundreds]", 
"on 15 August, an unreported amount of people drove their cars down the street. [size= no report]"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Hi Akrun, Thank you for your response. This works well for the problem I (was) facing, and runs very quickly! I also was under the impression that I had to loop through the data frame's columns to create the new "est_size" column, but in a way, this does that without explicitly calling a for-loop.  Much appreciated!